# get responseText of $.ajax call within a function and return it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a custom function. Inside this function is an `$.ajax` call that returns a string that I want to convert to JSON with `JSON.parse` and then return.

Now, I figured out how to return the string and then `JSON.parse` on other side when the data is returned. However, when I try to convert the string to JSON already in the function and return it – this does not work and I do not understand why.

My guess is that I do not understand how to handle the `$.ajax` return-object and how to retrieve the responseText from this object.

Here is my code;

```
$.plugin.ownfunction = function(options) {

    var promised_data = $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "plugin/php/somephp.php",
            data: opts
    })


    // this does not work
    // promised_data = JSON.parse(promised_data);

    // this also does not work
    // promised_data = JSON.parse(promised_data.responseText);

    return promised_data;
};
```

on the other side I do this;

```
$.database.readbehavior({ some options }).done(function(data) {

        // this does work – but I would like to do the JSON.parse already in the function
        var x = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(x);


});
```

---

edit:
I am sorry to disagree – but this is not a duplicate of the *How to return the response from an asynchronous call?* topic. I managed to return a response from an asynchronous call. The Problem is the format of this response that I have trouble with.

---

solution:
As Hacketo pointed out in the comments; Adding `dataType : "json"` to the `$.ajax` call returns the data as JSON. Problem solved! Thank You!

Comment: What are all these `return`? anything that is after a `return` statement will not be executed. In this case `def.resolve();` will not be executed after doing `return data;` . jQuery can handle JSON response [see docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) with adding `dataType : "json"` to the `$.ajax` settings

Comment: in your ajax call use this: `success: function(msg){promised_data = $.parseJSON(msg)}` Also remove `var promised_data = ` before ajax call and just declare your variable.

Comment: I see. I cleaned up the code – now there is only one return.

Comment: @grueb I updated my comment with jQuery stuff

Comment: @Tushar please read the entire posts before answering or flagging them..

Comment: wow. `dataType : "json"` solved it ... I assumed hat this specifies the data-type passed to PHP and not how to handle the return. Thank You so much!

Comment: @grueb by default `$.ajax` handle responses based on the MIME type, but you can force it with this parameter.

Comment: @Hacketo Please check the edit history of the question

Comment: @Tushar I saw it, and OP wanted to do the JSON.parse inside the promise, he already did the async callback stuff